# How do I turn this didSelectRowAtIndexPath into something useable with my storyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios

Ok so I am building the same project as I have built before but now I want to use a storyboard. I cannot use initWithNibName because I only have 1 storyboard of course.

This is the method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    ViewController2 *ViewController22 = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil]; // What to do instad of that nib thing?


    ViewController22.pickedRoww = indexPath.row;

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:ViewController22 animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The suggested method for dealing with navigation using storyboards is to use segues. [Here is a great tutorial showing you how to set this up](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/06/21/storyboard-segues.html).

Basically, you create a segue in the storyboard from your table viewcontroller to ViewController2. Then, in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, you call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegueId"];`.

Comment: You can add a "completion" to your answer with "Make sure you link the segue between view controllers because in case of UITableViewController you can link segue between cell and another UIViewController which will trigger the segue and the `didSelectRow` method will also trigger the push segue. ;)

Comment: But I don't have a TableViewController, I don't a fullscreen table but a smaller size and therefore it is harder. So Your answer honestly is not really what I need.

Comment: Sounds like you just want to copy/paste code, there I can't help you. Draw a segue from the view controller that contains your table view, name it, and call performSegueWithIdentifier from didSelectRowAtIndexPath (assuming the view controller is your tableview's datasource). An even easier way is to draw a segue from a prototype cell in your storyboard to ViewController2, then you don't even have to write any code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the Segue and set the values you need to set there. Especially on a push instead of a modal. I have had instances though where I needed to pop a modal view controller for one of my views in the storyboard that I didn't have a nib or a segue for. There's still a way to do that, thought I'd give you that info too just in case. In one of my apps I have this code that gets calld off of an alert sheet with a button, basically I want to present a modal view controller with the last lat and long so I can set up a new geofenced region.

My code looks like this:

```
-(void)createNewRegion
{
    UIStoryboard *mainboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *newRegionNavController = [mainboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"newRegionNav"];

    AlertDetailViewController *detailView = [newRegionNavController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

    //[detailView setupTableForNewRegion];

    [self presentViewController:newRegionNavController animated:YES completion:^(void){
        [detailView setupTableForNewRegion];
        detailView.longitude = self.lastLong;
        detailView.latitude = self.lastLat;
        detailView.mainController = self;
    }];
}
```

So almost exactly the same as the old method of instantiating a viewcontroller from a nib, except this time you're just doing it from a storyboard. Hope that helps some.

Comment: I honestly don't have a clue what things I have to change here to make it work for me :p